# merge 4 columns into 2 in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to clean up the raw data from 1 table and insert it into a new table.

- I have the following table

| ID | ActivePrimary | InactivePrimary | ActiveSecondary | InactiveSecondary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3 | - | - | 31,32,33,34 |
| 2 | 2 | 14,16 | 21 | 31,33,37 |
| 3 | 1,3,2,3 | 11,15,16 | 24,27,29 | - |
| 4 | 4,6,7,8,9 | 11 | 21,26,27 | 38 |
| 5 | - | - | 24,27 | 36,38,39 |
| 6 | - | - | - | - |

- I want to achieve the following
- I want to merge The **ActivePrimary** and **ActiveSecondary** as **Active**
- I want to merge The **InactivePrimary** and **InactiveSecondary** as **Inactive**

| ID | Active | Inactive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3 | 31,32,33,34 |
| 2 | 2,21 | 14,16,31,33,37 |
| 3 | 1,3,2,3,24,27,29 | 11,15,16 |
| 4 | 4,6,7,8,9,21,26,27 | 11,38 |
| 5 | 24,27 | 36,38,39 |
| 6 | null | null |

Notice that the Hyphen(-) is not there.

> I have the following query, but this also takes the Hyphen(-) and merges it like the example below

| ID | Active | Inactive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3,- | -,31,32,33,34 |

```
SELECT
  ID,
  CONCAT(AlarmsPrimaryActive, ",", AlarmsSecondaryActive) AS active,
  CONCAT(AlarmsPrimaryInactive, ",", AlarmsSecondaryInactive) AS active
FROM
  `table`
```

> For now I am trying to see if the select is working. After that I will insert it into a new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options here - consider below few approaches

Option 1

```
select id, 
  (select string_agg(value)
    from unnest(split(ActivePrimary) || split(ActiveSecondary)) value
    where value != '-' ) as Active,
  (select string_agg(value)
    from unnest(split(InactivePrimary) || split(InactiveSecondary)) value
    where value != '-' ) as Inactive  
from your_table
```

Option 2

```
select * from (
  select id, if(value = '-', null, value) as value, 
    regexp_extract(status, r'Active|Inactive') as status
  from your_table
  unpivot (value for status in (ActivePrimary,InactivePrimary,ActiveSecondary,InactiveSecondary))
)
pivot (string_agg(value) for status in ('Active', 'Inactive'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - both return below output

[image]